# How to compute texture in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, textures

[image: I want to compute the texture of the area under the green contour]

I have segmented 'the thyroid' in an Ultrasound image. In this figure, it is the area under the green contour. Now, I would like to compute the texture of that segmented part. How can I do that? I did a google search on computation of textures in an image but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: " I would like to compute the texture"- Can you describe in detail? may be with some pics?

Comment: @BalajiR I have uploaded the picture. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Do you have a book on image processing? Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez & Woods, a standard textbook, has sections on texture ID--segmentation, statistical measures, etc. Just to start things off you could look at Law's Texture measures--an early and simple method, but possibly useful in your case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_texture#Laws_Texture_Energy_Measures   With a bit more searching you should find quite a few papers on texture classification, "texture energy" measures, and so on.

Comment: @Rethunk Thanks,  I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you meant "feature characterization" or "feature descriptors". Then here is a non exhaustive list:

- Cooccurrence matrix with Haralick features (the most famous/used)
- Local Binary Pattern (LBP). Extremely simple/powerful descriptor used in most of application. It has the advantage of being gray level, rotation, translation invariant.
- Run Length Matrix. Useful for sequential/periodic texture (not in your case).
- Size Zone Matrix (SZM). Very powerful to discriminate between homogeneous/non homogeneous textures.
- Granulometry (see mathematical morphology).

Make your choice!